# Does the C++11 standard guarantee that the unary minus of a zero-valued signed integer is zero?

Tags: c++, c++11, integer, arithmetic-expressions, unary-operator

Does the C++11 standard guarantee that the unary minus of a zero-valued **signed integer** is zero?

For example:

```
int zero = 0;
int n = -zero;
int m = -0;
assert(memcmp(&n, &zero, sizeof(int)) == 0);
assert(memcmp(&m, &zero, sizeof(int)) == 0);
```

I know that `-0` and `0` are identical in two's compliment representation, but I'd like to know if the standard allows for the negation of signed integer zero to be negative-zero for other representations, such as one's compliment or signed-magnitude.

All I could find in the C++11 draft is §5.3.1, paragraph 8:

> The operand of the unary-operator shall have arithmetic or unscoped
>   enumeration type and **the result is the negation of its operand**.
>   Integral promotion is performed on integral or enumeration operands.
>   The negative of an unsigned quantity is computed by subtracting its
>   value from 2^n, where n is the number of bits in the promoted operand.
>   The type of the result is the type of the promoted operand.

I can't find a definition of *negation* within the draft.

**Motivation**: I'm writing a specialized integer number parser for a library (that may be open-sourced eventually) and I want to know if I should be concerned about the possibility of `"-0"` being interpreted as a negative-zero *signed integer* on uncommon architectures.

**Note**: I already know about negative-zero floating-point numbers.

Comment: -0 doesn't exist in assembly, Once the signed bit is set, there is no zero value in x86/x64.
 Nice question anyway.

Comment: I don't know if `zero` is considered an "unsigned quantity" according to the spec, even if `zero`'s datatype is signed.

Comment: At the C++ level it might be defined, but how will it implemented?  The code you have posted will set 0 and -0 to the same value in assembly generation. At the machine level there is no -0.

Comment: Any system that uses twos-complement under the hood has no internal way to represent negative-zero, and last I heard twos-complement was ubiquitous to the point of being nearly universal.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis On one-complement or signed-magnitude architectures, it's possible to represent a -0 integer, though I admit they are now rare. C++ is not (yet) strictly bound to two's compliment integers, though there is a proposal to make it so: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0907r0.html

Comment: @dmckee the first assembler I used was for a ones-complement machine.  Yes, I'm that old.

Comment: I realize my question is an academic one, as I don't foresee my library to be run on some old UNIVAC mainframe.

Comment: This is what I have; I'm sure the compiler will optimize that into a simple return expression on modern architectures: `if (isSignedOrUnsignedZeroString()) return negative ? ParseEvent{int{-0}} : ParseEvent{int{0}}`

Comment: There are no C++11 compilers for one's complement platforms so the question is about some other world.

Comment: The C standard specifies a limited set of operations that *may* produce a negative zero. Unary `-` is not in that set. (See [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) 6.2.6.2 paragraph 3.) I don't see any similar wording in the C++11 standard. In C, *negative zero* is a representation, not a value as such, and it compares equal to an ordinary zero. (And of course it doesn't exist in 2's-complement.)

Answer (score 0):

The standard does not mandate bit patterns for integers, because it is meant to be applicable to the widest possible range of machines.  It is entirely possible for a C++ compiler to use ones-complement, where zero and negative zero would be different.

Comment: It would require a redefinition of all the math on it, something impossible (and useless).

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis I don't see why that follows.  I've used a ones-complement processor, and I assure you math was not impossible.

Comment: You would break all 1-1 functions for example, because there would be two xs for one y.

Comment: @MarkRansom I understand the standard does not mandate bit patterns, but it could mandate the result of an arithmetic expression. I'm not well-versed enough in standardese to know if the latter it true.

Comment: My understanding is that [C++20 will mandate two's complement signed integers](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0907r0.html) (and C2x probably will too).  Of course, this question is specifically about C++11.

Comment: The question is whether a unary `-` applied to `0` can yield a negative zero representation. Hypothetically, the C++ standard *could* have said that such a result must be normalized to a normal `0` representation. See also my comment on the question regarding what C11 has to say about this (apparently more than C++11 does).

Comment: The standard does place several restrictions on the bit patterns used for integers

Comment: @M.M I would welcome an answer that quoted a relevant part of the standard.